# python program to store a specific string from a file and store it in a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

i want to store a specific string from a file ex:- "text.json"
and the file data be like

```
{
"my_name"    : "xylem",
"my_id"      : "a-123fdf21234",
"hey_there" :  "hello"
}
```

so i just want to get (a-123fdf21234) without any white spaces and any("")character and need to save them in a variable for ex:-M_Id
so that i can use it in my python script can anyone help me in this?
tell me for python 3
I am new to this and haven't tried any code

Comment: Try something after that ask here

Comment: Show the code you've tried, and specifically where you're having an issue.

Comment: For some starting guidance, you'll want to check out the [input/output python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) followed by the [python JSON API docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### First off

In your example json file you have inconsistent use of quotation marks, chose ' or " and stick to it.

### Code

```
import json
data = json.load(open("file.json"))
# this is the variable you are after
variable = data["my_id"]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your text format is json. In that case the answer is simple:

```
import json

with open('file.txt') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())
    # access the required key
    my_variable = data['my_id']
```